# Creating bottle using Blender Render for output to Blend4Web

Tags: modeling, blender-internal-render-engine

All the tutorials I can find use Cycles render for creating bottles. Because Blend4Web does not support Cycles --where can I go now to find learn how to create clear bottle with uv wrapped label BUT using the older Blender Render?

Comment: it's not that Blend4Web doesn't support Cycles. It doesn't support Cycles's nodes for material. You can try addons to convert cycles materials to blender internal materials. Either way, Blend4Web as it's own nodes, that you can use: https://www.blend4web.com/doc/en/node_materials.html

Answer (score 1):

Please see this model
https://www.blend4web.com/apps/webplayer/webplayer.html?load=../../assets/fridge/bottle/bottle.json
The source Blender file is only available in the Pro SDK though. Anyway, feel free to ask questions regarding this model on our forums.

Answer (score 0):

I am new for blender so this may be not wery accurate but I think that you can only use nodes in cycles render and as far as I know you can't make glass without nodes.

Comment: first off, he is asking how to make glass in the BI, not cycles. Second all cycles materials are node biased, however for something simple like glass you do not have to use the node editor.